# Can somebody merge my 3 accounts : Simon Boulanger; sorry not having register earlier

Tags: support, status-completed

I think there is no other Simon Boulanger in our community. I tried to find out how to do it, but did not. So if someone at the technical department would help, I would appreciate. I am registered to 4 of Stack Exchanges sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Project Management Stack Exchange, the site for expert and enthusiast project managers. It looks like the PMSE system recognizes your other 3 accounts. On your [user page](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/3268/simon-boulanger?tab=accounts), you appear to have membership on 3 other SE sites.

When you login to one site, as soon as you visit one of the others, it should recognize you.

UPDATE: I found one of your PMSE duplicates and merged it with the account you're using most recently. I don't see any others. Feel free to post links to them here if you have any more.

For other StackExchange sites, you'll likely need to contact the moderators there to merge any duplicate accounts.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel better having 85 reputations now!

Comment: You're welcome :)